# Parameter Sniffing Issue SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlclient

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 web application that has executes a *relavatively* simple parameterised dynamic query on a SQL Server 2016 database.

```
The query:
    select
        P.BusinessTypeId BusinessTypeId,
        BT.description BusinessTypeDescription,
        P.ProductFamilyId ProductFamilyId,
        P.ProductId ProductId,
        coalesce(PD.BrandedNm, P.nm) ProductNm,
        P.description ProductDescription,
        PLT.LifeTypeId LifeTypeId,
        LT.Description LifeTypeDescription,
        S.SellerId SellerId,
        S.SellerNm SellerNm,
        P.HasProductSubtypeCd HasProductSubtypeCd,
        P.HasProdsubCommissionCd HasProdsubCommissionCd,
        P.PensionTypeId PensionTypeId,
        PT.Description PensionTypeDescription,
        P.IsSinglePremiumOnlyCd IsSinglePremiumOnlyCd,
        P.PensionSubtypeCd PensionSubtypeCd,
        P.PrsaPaymentTypeCd PrsaPaymentTypeCd,
        PS.ProductSubtypeId ProductSubtypeId,
        PS.Description ProductSubtypeDescription,
        p.AdviceDrivenProduct AdviceDrivenProduct
    FROM
        seller S
        inner join ProductDistribution PD on S.DistributionId = PD.DistributionId
        inner join Product P on PD.ProductFamilyId = P.ProductFamilyId and PD.ProductId = P.ProductId
        inner join ProductLifeType PLT on P.ProductFamilyId = PLT.ProductFamilyId and P.ProductId = PLT.ProductId
        inner join BusinessType BT on P.BusinessTypeId = BT.BusinessTypeId
        inner join LifeType LT on PLT.LifeTypeId = LT.LifeTypeId
        left join PensionType PT on P.PensionTypeId = PT.PensionTypeId
        left join SpecialDistributionSeller SDS on S.SellerId = SDS.SellerId
        left join ProductSubtype PS on P.ProductFamilyId = PS.ProductFamilyId and P.ProductId = PS.ProductId
    where
        S.SellerId = @sellerIdParam
        and SDS.SpecialDistributionSeq IS NULL
        and P.StatusCd = 'O'
        and (P.AvailabilityCd = 'A'
            OR (P.AvailabilityCd = 'P' AND @posUserTypeId = '2')
            OR (P.AvailabilityCd = 'I' and @posUserTypeId != '2'))
        and exists (
            select ProductCommissionSeq
            from ProductCommission PC
                inner join CommissionTemplate CT on PC.CommissionTemplateSeq = CT.CommissionTemplateSeq
            where PC.ProductFamilyId = P.ProductFamilyId
                and PC.ProductId = P.ProductId
                and (CT.AvailabilityCd = 'A'
                    or (CT.AvailabilityCd = 'P' and @posUserTypeId ='2')
                    or (CT.AvailabilityCd = 'I' and @posUserTypeId !='2'))
                and (PC.DistributionId = S.DistributionId
                    or PC.CommissionGroupSeq IN (select CommissionGroupSeq from CommissionGroupSeller where SellerId = @sellerIdParam))
        )
```

This query has two parameters:

- `@sellerIdParam`
- `@posUserTypeId`

These are both VARCHAR data types (5) and (2) length respectively.

For almost all parameter combinations this query completes execution almost instantly. However we have an issue where the combination:

- `@sellerIdParam` - "RR39"
- `@posUserTypeId` - "1"

Is timing out on execution (default of 30 seconds using `System.Data.SqlClient`).

The equivalent query with parameters combination:

- `@sellerIdParam` - "RR30"
- `@posUserTypeId` - "1"

Works absolutely fine and returns immediately.

This seems like a classic Parameter Sniffing (spoofing) issue. The best defence for this in this situation from my analysis is amending the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` hint to the end of the query. I have tried this and it seems to make no difference. This has worked in the past for similar issues but this time it seems to not make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated as for the life of me I cannot get this query to complete execution in an appropriate amount of time.

**EDIT**

To answer some questions from the comments:

Have you attempted the same query in SSMS? Yes this completes execution almost immediately with either set of parameters. The exact same query is used with:

```
DECLARE @sellerIdParam VARCHAR(4) = 'RR39'-- or 'RR30';
DECLARE @posUserTypeId VARCHAR(1) = '1';
```

Prepended to the query.

Does RR39 have more / less data in the database than RR30? No there is no difference. Both queries return 100 records as well with almost identical data.

C# code (I don't think this is the issue as this same code is used for hundreds of other working queries and works for the same query in most parameter combinations):

```
public DbDataReader ExecuteReader(string commandText, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    DbConnection conn = null;

    try
    {
        var result = this.Factory.CreateConnection();
        result.ConnectionString = this.ConnectionString;
        conn = result;
        var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            var param = this.Factory.CreateParameter();
            if (param == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            param.ParameterName = item.Key;
            param.Value = item.Value ?? DBNull.Value;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        conn.Open();
        return cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (conn != null)
        {
           conn.Close();
           conn.Dispose();
        }

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.Stop();

        Log.Debug(() => Helpers.SqlInfo(commandText, parameters, sw.Elapsed));
    }
}
```

Execution Plan for 'RR39'/'1': https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJ8jaNyXt

Execution Plan for 'RR30'/'1': https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJquREJ7F

Seller table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Seller](
    [SellerId] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [DistributionId] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [InspId] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [AreaId] [varchar](7) NULL,
    [EmpId] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [TypeCd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [SubdivisionCd] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [SellerNm] [varchar](70) NULL,
    [Addr1Txt] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Addr2Txt] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Addr3Txt] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [MasterSellerId] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [EmailAddrTxt] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PosUwTypeCd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [LastUpdDt] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastUpdId] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [ESignatureAllowedCd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [AppointmentDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [IsSiebelSeller] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [Addr4Txt] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [CrmPrimaryOwnerCd] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [InstAgentRoleCd] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [PriceMatchAllowedCd] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [LooserValidationBusType] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CommissionScreen2BusType] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [CentralBankAuthorisedInd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [NewAmlAllowedCd] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [BusinessName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [MagnumPureAllowedCd] [varchar](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Seller_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SellerId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [ESignatureAllowedCd]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller] ADD  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [PriceMatchAllowedCd]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [LooserValidationBusType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [CommissionScreen2BusType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller] ADD  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [CentralBankAuthorisedInd]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [SellerDistrib_FK] FOREIGN KEY([DistributionId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Distribution] ([DistributionId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Seller] CHECK CONSTRAINT [SellerDistrib_FK]
GO
```

CommissionGroupSeller table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CommissionGroupSeller](
    [CommissionGroupSeq] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [SellerId] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CreateId] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [COMGRPSEL_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CommissionGroupSeq] ASC,
    [SellerId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CommissionGroupSeller]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ComGrpSel_CommGroup_Fk] FOREIGN KEY([CommissionGroupSeq])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CommissionGroup] ([CommissionGroupSeq])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CommissionGroupSeller] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ComGrpSel_CommGroup_Fk]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CommissionGroupSeller]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [ComGrpSel_Seller_Fk] FOREIGN KEY([SellerId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Seller] ([SellerId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CommissionGroupSeller] CHECK CONSTRAINT [ComGrpSel_Seller_Fk]
GO
```

Comment: Have you 1) attempted the same query in SSMS and 2) inspected the execution plan?

Comment: Are the statistics up to date? You can try to inspect execution plan ```SELECT UseCounts, Cacheobjtype, Objtype, TEXT, query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)```

Comment: Do you get the same issue if executing the same _parameterised_ query in SSMS directly?

Comment: Does RR39 have more / less data in the database than RR30?

Comment: Yea we need to see the actual execution plans for both, as the RR39 sounds like is has loads more data, how selective is RR30 and RR39. Save the execution plan as xml when right clicking on it and then paste it in here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan then share the query plan url value it gives you.

Comment: Please share both execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. We cannot answer this without it. Table and index definitions would help also. I'm guessing that `PC.DistributionId = S.DistributionId or PC.CommissionGroupSeq IN (select CommissionGroupSeq ....` is causing you trouble, because of the `or`. Also `SpecialDistributionSeller` should probably be a `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Please see edits for some question answers. I have tried to view the execution plan but I do not have SHOWPLAN permissions on this DB (I'm a software developer not the DBA) I only only db_datareader and db_datawriter permissions. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Ben The problem is caused by catch-all clauses like `(P.AvailabilityCd = 'P' AND @posUserTypeId = '2')`. If the query is dynamic, you know in advance whether that clause is needed at all. With the catch-all clause the server will cache the execution plan of the first execution and decide to use a table scan instead of an index seek.

Comment: Side note: the C# code is fundamentally broken. The connection and reader need to be in `using` blocks, meanwhile you are passing back a reader and not disposing the connection at all in event of no exception. It's also using rather verbose syntax for creating the connection and parameters

Comment: How do you generate the SQL query? You may be able to eliminate the catch-all and generate either `P.AvailabilityCd  IN ('A','P')` or `P.AvailabilityCd IN ('A','I')` as needed

Comment: I've attached Execution plans. @PanagiotisKanavos this makes sense that it would create an inefficient query. The query is generated as a string in C'# so it could definitely be manipulated as per what you say but is that really the root cause here? The query does work as expected for most inputs.

Comment: @Ben the difference between an index seek and a full table scan in a table of 100K rows can be huge - worst case, almost 100K worse. With a table scan, the server has to read all 100K rows. With an index seek it may only have to look into a single index page

Comment: @Ben that difference can also change the rest of the plan. The server will generate different execution plans if it knows that only a few rows would match the criteria. It would use different join operators to join to data from the rest of the query

Comment: 95% the chance the problem is that your parameters aren't varchar (which is why SSMS is faster - since its parameters _are_ varchar), they are nvarchar. Set the type explicitly to `VarChar` - then you will be able to do index seeks rather than scans.

Comment: Please share the `CREATE TABLE` script for `seller` and `CommissionGroupSeller`.

Comment: @mjwills see edits for this detail

Comment: Yep, you are passing nvarchar parameters and comparing to varchar columns. This is a very bad idea. 99% chance it is causing your issue. You need to set the type to varchar.

Comment: @mjwills would wrapping the `@sellerIdParam` in quotes force this to varchar? I noticed that doing this i.e.: `select CommissionGroupSeq from CommissionGroupSeller where SellerId = '@sellerIdParam'` seems to make this query return immediately.

Comment: **Do not wrap it in quotes.** You need to set `param.Type`.

Comment: @mjwills setting the param type to `DbType.AnsiString` (rather than `DbType.String`) did fix this. I think this is the generic `System.Data` parameter version but essentially the same thing with unicode/non unicode. Why is wrapping the parameter in quotes bad? that works as well.

Comment: `that works as well.` No it doesn't. If you do that, it will search the database for the value of `'@sellerIdParam'` (not your parameter). You really should set the length of the parameter as well to avoid plan cache pollution https://blog.greglow.com/2015/06/04/plan-cache-pollution-avoiding-it-and-fixing-it/ .